# String column sorting Sql select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem in a sql query, is returning me a cluttered result, I wanted to guide you to follow the number before the comma, I do not know if you can follow the example:

```
SELECT responsaveis FROM public.pasrem_view where seqalu = 444111;
```

Result:

```
"DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,LILIANA LETICIA CARVALHO THEODORO-00163264155-FILIACAO1,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2"
```

I would like you to return to me like this:

```
"LILIANA LETICIA CARVALHO THEODORO-00163264155-FILIACAO1,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2"
```

**Remembering that it is just a result, and the field is a String separated by ","**

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cdf790d74b053ef8289e428eed0bd62e

Comment: SQL Server or PostgreSQL? Isn't the just `responsaveis` in descending order? What about your attempt (the SQL doesn't have an `ORDER BY` so isn't your attempt) did not work?

Comment: postgresql and sqlserver

Comment: `order by the_column DESC`?

Comment: Show us your current `ORDER BY` attempt.

Comment: "...the number before the comma..." -- do you mean the single digit, or any integer with multiple digits? What about floating point numbers?

Comment: @RomeuStack . . . There are no commas in the sample data.

Comment: Add the row `LILIANA LETICIA CARVALHO THEODORO-00163264155-FILIACAO3,`, and adjust the wanted result accordingly.

Comment: I think the OP means the comma at the end up each row's value, @GordonLinoff . I.e. `'DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2,'`. not that it'll have any effect on the order of the data.

Comment: *"postgresql and sqlserver"* what do you mean ***and***? An RDBMS isn't both, it's one or the other. Both use different dialects of SQL.

Comment: This result of my query is a concatenated string, I want to sort a concatenated string, the result looks like this: DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, LILIANA LETICIA CARVALHO THEODORO -00163264155-FILIACAO1, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2

Comment: Sample data in the comments like that doesn't help us. Put information like that in your question by [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59718961/edit) it.

Comment: *"I want to sort a concatenated string"* then tell us the RDBMS you are *really* using...

Comment: Do you mean you get a **single** row from your query and the content of the **column** is a comma separated value? And you want _that_ value to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first unnest the elements into rows (essentially normalizing your data model "on-the-fly") then you can aggregate it back into a sorted string:

```
SELECT string_agg(trim(t.element), ',' order by t.element desc)
FROM public.pasrem_view 
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(responsaveis, ',')) as t(element)
where seqalu = 444111;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0afa3c911bb40d3cd24d92d8c38e5cda)

Comment: Error ocurred: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
  Position: 142

Comment: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function string_to_arry(text, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 108 error ocurred

Comment: @RomeuStack: another typo, fixed

Comment: Result: DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, LILIANA LETICIA CARVALHO THEODORO -00163264155-FILIACAO1, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, DIOGO LUIZ BORDON DE SOUZA-89812239120-FILIACAO2, observale liliane not in primary in string

Comment: @RomeuStack: this returns exactly the string you showed us in your question - did you check the online example?

Comment: Your query is working perfectly, but I would like him to look at the last number 1 or 2. (FILIACAO1,FILIACAO2)

Comment: Then change the `order by` in the string_agg - you should have mentioned that in your question - everybody who answered had to guess

Comment: Desculpe pelo transtorno sou novo com este tipo de consulta,

Answer (score 0):

Your question refers to a number before a comma.  But there are no commas in the sample data.  For your results, a descending sort would work:

```
SELECT responsaveis
FROM public.pasrem_view 
WHERE seqalu = 444111
ORDER BY responsaveis DESC;
```

Comment: It should be ordered by the "01" and "02".

Comment: @RomeuStack spamming the comments doesn't help us help you. Fix your question; clearly you aren't giving us the real picture if `ORDER BY responsaveis DESC` isn't working (which it would with the sample we have) [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0488e1b72b72cb93d4b90c458a48403)